# Use multiple specific network interfaces with docker swarm

Tags: linux, docker, networking, docker-swarm, rhel

I am using docker swarm to deploy an on-premise third party application. The machine I am deploying on is running RHEL 7.6 and has two network interfaces. The users will interact with the application from `eth0`, but internal communication with their system must use `eth1` or the connection will be blocked by their firewalls. My application requires some of my services to establish connections internal services in their network.

I created my swarm using:

```
$ docker swarm init --advertise-addr x.x.x.x
```

Where `x.x.x.x` is the `eth0` inet address. This works for incoming user traffic to the service. However, when I try to establish connections to another service the connection times out, blocked by the firewall.

Outside of docker, on the machine, I can run:

```
ssh -b y.y.y.y user@server
```

Where `y.y.y.y` is the `eth1` inet address, and it works. When I run the same in my docker swarm container I get this error:

> bind: y.y.y.y: Cannot assign requested address

Is there some way I can use multiple network interfaces with docker swarm and specify which one is used within containers? I couldn't find much documentation on this. Do I need to set up some sort of proxy?

Comment: Why not use the `--data-path-addr` as mentioned in https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/swarm/networking/#use-a-separate-interface-for-control-and-data-traffic

Comment: Unfortunately, I am trying to connect between two nodes. Both of them can run totally independently, the connection is just a non-blocking background process. If I make them part of the same swarm they will both go down if one of them goes down. Is there a way I can change this behavior? I know it's not a good setup but I really don't have any choice in that.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Docker creates a bridged network from the network interfaces on your machine and then attaches each container instance to it via a separate virtual interface internally. So you would not be able to bind to eth1 directly as your Docker container has a different interface.

See https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/ for a general guide and https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/ for custom bridged networks with multiple physical interfaces.